# Difference between Carbon object inserted on DB and printed on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, php-carbon

I have a doubt, if I create a Carbon object in PHP with Carbon:now() and I insert it on my DB the row shows '2018-12-26 14:56:00' but if I print it it gives me a carbon object, why does this happen?

Comment: how are you `if I print it it gives me a carbon object` printing it.  Carbon is just an extension of DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code (briefly)

```
/**
 * Default format to use for __toString method when type juggling occurs.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

And I know the magic `__toString` method is called when outputting such as `echo` or `print` but not `var_dump`, `var_export` and `print_r`.  But it actually affects casting the object to string (not really dependent on output).  It's just that using things like `var_dump` and "friends" does not convert it to a string first.

For example ,we can "prove this" quite easily

```
class foo{

    public function __toString(){
        return "foo";
    }
}

$f = new foo;

print_r($f);

echo "\n";

echo $f;

echo "\n\n";

print_r((string)$f);
```

Output

```
foo Object //output from print_r
(
) 

foo //output from echo

foo //output from casting to string and print_r
```

So to answer your question, that is because you are using something other then `echo` and the class is designed to output that when converting it to a string.

So once you combine that with that little piece I found in the source code, well it all makes sense.

- 1. Your outputting it in a way that does not convert it to a string
- 2. When it's converted to a string it's designed to use that format.

And without even looking at the `toString` method I can bet it contains something like this:

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->format(static::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT); //or self::
}
```

And in fact (After some digging) we find it in a "Trait" [Here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Traits/Converter.php)

```
public function __toString()
{
    $format = $this->localToStringFormat ?? static::$toStringFormat;
    return $format instanceof Closure
        ? $format($this)
        : $this->format($format ?: (
            defined('static::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT')
                ? static::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT
                : CarbonInterface::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT
        ));
}
```

I can also tell (By looking at that) that you can probably set one of these 2:

```
 $this->localToStringFormat
 static::$toStringFormat
```

To override that behavior (either as a anon function, or as a call to it's own format method), of what the format it returns when cast to a string.

And I never used Carbon before!!

Cheers.

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/730bb35ee0ddb184f10ac753e4c79630af7616e9)